# gcloud deploy fails on a weired "Access to project ID trainer-messenger-server is denied"

Tags: firebase, gcloud, google-cloud-platform

I followed the docs and entered:

```
$ gcloud beta functions deploy helloWorld --stage-bucket serverless-example-bucket1 --trigger-http
```

and I get:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Forbidden], message=[Access to project ID trainer-messenger-server is denied]
```

What is this trainer-messenger-server project I don't have such a project? how do I point the deployment to a specific project?

Comment: What happens when you run `gcloud config list`?

Comment: You'll need to make some modifications at the config files such as app.yaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a project via `gcloud config set my-project` or providing the flag `--project`.

To see projects that you have access to, run `gcloud projects list`.